# issue while calling zendesk real time chat api

Tags: oauth-2.0, zendesk, zendesk-api

can anyone help me I am trying to call below request

```
curl https://rtm.zopim.com/stream/{resource} \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer {API access token}"
```

initially, I tried with basic auth (adding id : password in the request) response was unauthorized,

then I generate access token with postman like in below screenshot

and when call API with that access token then the response is 403 forbidden

I can successfully hit and get response other api like ( https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats) with the same access token

but not the specific **"rtm.zopim.com/stream/"**

[image]

Comment: What's your Zendesk Chat plan tier?  Do you have access to the real time monitor in the UI?  If you're not on Enterprise you may not be able to access this API endpoint.

Comment: thank Jimmy Long , I checked and our account was not to enterprise this was the reason for my issue.

Comment: As that is the case, I've just added it as an answer.  Please confirm the answer at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Real Time Chat API is available on Enterprise plans only, so if you are not on the Enterprise plan you will receive a 403 Forbidden error.